Undefined symbol: _GDTCCTConstructiOSClientInfo _GDTCCTNetworkConnectionInfoNetworkMobileSubtype
I have the following problem when compiling my React Native application in XCode Version 15.3 (15E204a)
`Undefined symbol: _GDTCCTConstructiOSClientInfo
Undefined symbol: _GDTCCTNetworkConnectionInfoNetworkMobileSubtype
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
package.json
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "14.12.0",

Pod File
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '6.29.0'
platform :ios, '15.0'

 - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.5.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.7)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - FirebaseCrashlytics (4.3.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.8)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 1.1)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 7.0)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)

  - GoogleDataTransport (7.2.0):
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)



build my react native app in xcode
